# What does this Symbol mean? (Characters Identified: 招財進寶)

Tags: meaning, character-identification

Please help me if you know what does this Symbol mean.
Thank you for your help! [image: symbol]

[image: symbol 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lucky symbol for business. It consists/made out of 4 words - 招財進寶 (wish more money to come),

Comment: Thank you @r13!  Do you know if the second Image (looks more blurry) has the same meaning?   https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7RHp.jpg

Comment: Both are the same.

Comment: Really Appreciated! Thanks for your time and help @r13!

Comment: You are welcome. it is my pleasure to be helpful.